# Universal hashing - insert / search / delete

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, hashing

I don't understand the highlighted text below in [CLRS 3rd Ed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms):

[image]

I'm not sure I even understand what the sentence is trying to say. For example:

- What do they mean by "... ***operations*** containing $\mathcal{O}(m)$ INSERT **operations**"?  Which operations contain which?
- If the (total) expected time is $\Theta(n)$ how can any of these operations **contain** other $\mathcal{O}(m)$ operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain this with an example. Let us say if m=10 and n=1000.
If I have m number of insertions in a table with m slots, it is going to be O(m). Right?
But if we have 1000 insertions in a table containing 10 slots, it is not the same math anymore. Since you will have to deal with collisions at a greater frequency. It no more remains linear math. Thus if the n stays small enough that it is in order of O(m), you can have expected Theta n for n inserts. If inserts increase at a number much greater than m, the collisions doesn't let it be linear.

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you wrote but I still don't understand what the original Corollary is trying to say, sorry. I updated my question to make my confusion even more explicit.